# (Godot Engine) Multiple buttons play the animation on first button

Tags: animation, godot

I have two buttons, each with its own animation player but the same animations.

[right button plays animation on the left button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIMDe.png)
[animation card_flip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qCwj.png)
[node structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI8Vc.png)

Both buttons reference the same script.

```
    func _on_Card_pressed() -> void:
    $AnimationPlayer.play("card_flip")
```

My intention is:
If I push the first button the animation "card_flip" is played on the first button, if I press the 2nd button the animation is played on the 2nd button.
But if I press the 2nd button the animation is played on the first button.

One solution would probably be to duplicate the animations and rename it eg. "card_flip_2"
But I'm pretty sure there is an easier way.

Any suggestions appreciated
Thanks Boris

Answer (score 0):

Think I found solution:

- create for 1 card, which contains the animation player its own scene
- set for the animation "local to scene" true
- add this scene to the main scene tree